# How to test a specific javax custom validator that uses JPA repositories?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I've been working in a Java project (1.8 and 11) for the past few months. We are trying to code every validation we have in our models as a custom javax validation, which I think is the "best" method I've found so far (open to new suggestions as always)...
The issue, though, is when this validator needs to fetch data from the database and multiple validators for the same model/entity.

Entity

```
@DuplicatedUsername
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    private UUID id;
    private String username;
    public User(username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Validator

```
public class DuplicatedUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DuplicatedUsername, User> {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(User user, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (user.getId() != null) {
      return checkForDuplicatedUsername(user.getUsername(), user.getId());
    } else {
      return checkForDuplicatedUsername(user.getUsername());
    }
  }

  private boolean checkForDuplicatedUsername(String username) {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    return users.isEmpty();
  }

  private boolean checkForDuplicatedUsername(String username, UUID id) {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findByUsernameAndIdNot(username, id);
    return users.isEmpty();
  }
}
```

Test file

```
    private static Validator validator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpValidator() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository repository; 

    public void givenDuplicatedSettings_whenValidate_thenReturnInvalid() {
        String username = "duplicated";

        User user = new User(username);

        when(repository.findByUsername(username))
                .thenReturn(new User(username));

        // What I have
        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(user);
        assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());

        // What I would like to have
        // validator here must be DuplicatedUsernameValidator
        assertFalse(validator.isValid(user));
    }
```

The main reason for this is that User may have other validators, and I don't want to validate them as a single unit.

This is the first issue... The second is related to spring contexts (as always)... The above code, even with `Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(user);` doesn't work due to repository being null in the validator code. It's not being injected correctly even though when I run it, it's working as expected. I've been using the following annotations `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, `@DataJpaTest`, and the following code:

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public Validator validator(){
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
```

None of them working as expected. Which piece of the puzzle am I getting wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using the `Import` annotation. The other answers also work, so it's a matter of preference

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import(DuplicatedUsernameValidator.class)
public class DuplicatedUsernameValidatorTest {

    @Aurowired
    private DuplicatedUsernameValidator validator;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository repository; 

    public void givenDuplicatedSettings_whenValidate_thenReturnInvalid() {
        String username = "duplicated";

        User user = new User(username);

        when(repository.findByUsername(username))
                .thenReturn(new User(username));

        assertFalse(validator.isValid(user));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [@TestConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html) for this purpose. For example leave your classes at presented in original post state and add to test class those lines:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class DuplicatedUsernameValidatorTestContextConfiguration {

    //for 'validator.validate(user);' usecase
    @Bean
    public Validator employeeService() {
       return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    //for 'validator.isValid(user,null)' usecase
    @Bean
    public DuplicateEmployeeValidator employeeService() {
       return new DuplicateEmployeeValidator();
    }
}

@Autowired
private DuplicateEmployeeValidator dupValidator;

@Autowired
private Validator validator;

// private static Validator validator;

// @BeforeClass
// public static void setUpValidator() {
//     ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
//     validator = factory.getValidator();
// }

@MockBean
private UserRepository repository;
```

there is no need for adding @DataJpaTest, UserRepository will be injected in validators beans automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I will try it out. I found another approach which is to use the `@Import(DuplicateEmployeeValidator.class)`. It still requires the `@DataJpaTest`, though in order to load the correct context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally not a huge fan of all the annotation driven unit tests and would suggest simply adding a constructor to you `DuplicatedUsernameValidator` class that would allow you to set the `UserRepository` at construction time.

```
public class DuplicatedUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DuplicatedUsername, User> {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  // NEW!
  public DuplicatedUsernameValidator(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(User user, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then in your test, I would consider do the following:

```
private static DuplicatedUsernameValidator validator;

@MockBean
private UserRepository repository; 

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpValidator() {
    // We're not testing the factory here, I would NOT use it...
    // Perhaps the factory should have its own test...
    //ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = new DuplicatedUsernameValidator(repository);
}

public void givenDuplicatedSettings_whenValidate_thenReturnInvalid() {
    //I appreciate the use of the given_when_then method names.
}
```

The following comments are hidden in the above code snippets:

- I would recommend NOT using the `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()` call in your unit test.  Tests, in general, should only be testing the class under test, I feel that this is actually testing two things.
- If you need to see the `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()` method work, then I would recommend that you have a separate test for that class/method.
- I really appreciate the use of [GivenWhenThen](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html) unit test method names.

Comment: Yeah, I was also avoiding to use the `buildDefaultValidatorFactory`. Not only because it adds another layer to the unit test (which should be as isolated and "unit" as possible), but also because the validator validates the entire `User`, so every other validation would be checked. I definitely don't want that.
I'm trying to be more diligent on the GivenWhenThen, it's really helpful.
Like I said in another answer, I was able to fix this by adding the `@Import(DuplicateEmployeeValidator.class)` + `@DataJpaTest`